# how to perform a join query with field references with different names using GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

How to perform a join query with field references with different names using GORM
like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tickets JOIN ticket_details ON tickets.ticket_id = ticket_details.ticket_id JOIN users ON tickets.create_user = users.user_id JOIN employees ON users.employee_id = employees.employee_id
```

**tickets.create_user = users.user_id** without foreignkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this by using the "Joins"

https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins

the query that you provided should be done with this kind of Joins:

```
db.Model(...).Joins("JOIN ticket_details ON tickets.ticket_id = ticket_details.ticket_id").Joins("JOIN users ON tickets.create_user = users.user_id").Joins("JOIN employees ON users.employee_id = employees.employee_id")...
```

if you want to set the relation in your model between the Tickets and Users

I assume the relation is User "has many" Tickets

and the ID of the model User/Ticket is int64

then you could do this by set the gorm "foreignKey" and "references"

https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key

https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Override-References

```
type Ticket struct {
    TicketId int64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreateUser int64
}

type User struct {
    UserId  int64    `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Tickets []Ticket `gorm:"foreignKey:CreateUser;references:UserId"`
}
```

then you should be able to query users with tickets like this

```
var users []User
db.Joins("Tickets").Find(&users)
```